# Search for projection on a special matrix space with regard to Frobenius norm(computer vision background)

Tags: matrices, rotations, numerical-optimization, svd

**Background**

Define essential space as 
$$\varepsilon=\{E \in \mathbb R^{3\times3}|E=\hat{T}R\}$$
$$\hat{T}\in\{S\in \mathbb R^{3\times3}|S^T=-S\}$$
$$R\in\{A\in\mathbb R^{3\times3}|A^TA=I,\det(A)=1\}$$
that is any matrix $E \in \varepsilon$ is skew-symmetric matrix $\hat T$ post-multiplied by a rotation matrix R.

According to [this paper](https://www.csd.uoc.gr/~hy576/bibliography/E_matrix.pdf), $E$ resides in $\varepsilon$ if and only if 
$$E=U\Sigma V^T,\Sigma = diag(\sigma,\sigma,0).$$

**Optimization Problem**

For a matrix $F \in \mathbb R^{3\times 3}$, searching it's projection on the essential space can be considered as solving following optimization problem:
$$\arg\min_{E} \|F-E\|_F^2 $$
$$s.t. \qquad E \in \varepsilon.$$
Suppose $F=Udiag(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3) V^T$, then solution to above problem is 
$$E = Udiag(\sigma,\sigma,0) V^T, \sigma = \frac{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}{2}$$

**Question**

Let $E=U_1diag(\sigma,\sigma,0)V_1^T$ be any matrix in $\varepsilon$. I have derived above solution if $U_1=U,V_1=V$, but stuck on cases in which $U_1\ne U$ or $V_1 \ne V$.

Comment: In what sense can $U_1\neq U$? haven't you just defined them as equal?

Comment: @user617446 Not equal in definition. To my understanding, the only constraint is $E \in \varepsilon $ (i.e. $E=Udiag(\sigma,\sigma,0)V^T$) which does not necessarily make $F=Udiag(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)V^T$

Comment: Are you asking _why_ $E$ is the optimal solution given $F$? Your definition of $E$ is based on $F$ and hence on $U,V$, so $E$ _must_ be $E = Udiag(\sigma,\sigma,0) V^T, \sigma = \frac{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}{2}$

Comment: @user617446 I didn't mention definition of $E$ is based on $F$ in this post, the only constraint is $E \in \varepsilon$. I derived the solution when I enforcing additional constraints that $U=U_1,V=V_1$.

Comment: @user617446 I wonder how to arrive without above additional constraints.

Comment: Unfortunately I still don't follow. Did you take an known  $F=Udiag(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)V^T$ and optimise the Frobenius norm for $E\in \epsilon$ ? Are you saying that the form you found was _not_ decomposable to $U \diag(\sig,sig,0)V$ for the _known_ values of $U,V$? You may want to consult theorem 5 in http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.64.7518